# JCR SQL2 query comparing dates

Tags: date, jcr

I'm having a hard time finding out to compare dates using the SQL2 query language.

I want to be able to do stuff like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM [nt:base] AS p WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.[some_date]) = "2008"
```

Is it possible?  What are the best techniques for these king of constraints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to use dates in a query is to use `CAST` to force the conversion of a string representation of a date/time into a DATE value used by JCR.

Unfortunately, in your example you're looking for a date that occurs within a particular year. There's no way in JCR to extract the year as an integer, so the only standard way I know of is to check whether the actual date occurs within a range defined by the first the first and last microsecond of the year:

```
SELECT p.* FROM [nt:base] AS p
WHERE p.[some_date] >= CAST('2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' AS DATE)
  AND p.[some_date] <= CAST('2008-12-31T23:59:59.999Z' AS DATE)
```

You can of course use a long representation (the number of milliseconds past epoch) rather than the string literal.

This becomes much easier if you have some kind of 'year' property:

```
SELECT p.* FROM [nt:base] AS p
WHERE p.[some_year] = 2008
```

You could also use a string literal and force a cast to LONG:

```
SELECT p.* FROM [nt:base] AS p
WHERE p.[some_year] = CAST('2008' AS LONG)
```

If the `some_year` property is defined on a property definition to be LONG, then some implementations may discover this and auto-convert during planning.